# Vue 3 Option api: Parent element not receiving v-model input from child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, v-model

I'm working on a Nuxt 3 project and facing an issue with a contact form where the parent element doesn't seem to be receiving the input values from a child component. Here's a breakdown of my code:

Parent Component:

```
<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    const formElement = ref(null);

    const errorMessage = ref(null);
    const form = ref({
        name: null,
        subject: null,
        email: null,
        message: null
    });

    const submitForm = () => {
        if (!form.value.name || !form.value.subject || !form.value.message) {
            console.log(form.value);
            errorMessage.value = "please make sure your 'fullname', 'subject', and 'message' fields are filled";
        } else if (!/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(form.value.email)) {
            errorMessage.value = "please fill in a valid 'email'";
        } else if (form.value.message.length < 3) {
            errorMessage.value = "please add some more context to the 'message'";
        } else {
            console.log("button clicked");
            console.log(form.value);
            formSubmit();
        }
    };

    const formSubmit = () => {
        const formElement = document.querySelector('form');
        console.log(formElement);
        // formElement.submit();
    };
</script>

<template>
<form action="https://formsubmit.co/info@example.co.uk" method="POST" ref="formm">
        <UtilityMainInput name="Name" placeholder="Full Name" inputType="text" controlType="input" v-model="form.name"/>
    <UtilityMainInput name="Subject" placeholder="Subject" inputType="text" controlType="input" v-model="form.subject"/>
    <UtilityMainInput name="Email" placeholder="Email Address" inputType="email" controlType="input" v-model="form.email"/>
    <UtilityMainInput name="Message" placeholder="Tell us anything" inputType="textarea" controlType="textarea" v-model="form.message"/>
    <div class="empty-height"></div>
    <UtilityButton type="btn" size="medium" :onClick="submitForm">Send Message</UtilityButton>
</form>
</template>
```

Child Component (UtilityMainInput):

```
<template>
    <div class="normal-form">
        <label :for="name" class="label">
            {{name}}
        </label>

        <!-- text input -->
        <input 
            v-if="controlType === 'input' && inputType ==='text'" 
            type="text" 
            maxlength="50"
            :name="name" 
            :value="value" 
            @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value) ">
        <!-- email input -->
        <input 
            v-if="controlType === 'input' && inputType ==='email'" 
            type="email" 
            :name="name" 
            :value="value" 
            @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value) ">
        <!-- textarea input -->
        <div class="textarea" v-if="controlType === 'textarea'">
            <textarea  
                :name="name" 
                :value="value"
                @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value) ">
            </textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    props: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        placeholder: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: "text goes here"
        },
        inputType: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: "text"
        },
        controlType: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: 'input'
        },
        value: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

When I fill in the form and click submit, I get null for all values in the parent component's data properties, even though I've used v-model to bind them. Can someone help identify why the parent is not updating with the child's input values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this [breaking change](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-model.html#v-model) in Vue 3 that you should follow in Option api. for more info read [official docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#component-v-model) as well.

Vue 2 version:

```js
<input
  :value="name"
  @input="name= $event.target.value"
/>
```

Vue 3 version (Both Option api and Composition api):

- `value` -> `modelValue`
- `@input` -> `@update:modelValue`

```js
<CustomInput
  :model-value="name"
  @update:model-value="newValue => name = newValue"
/>
```

---

The updated code to your files is as follows: [check it in Vue playground if you want](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import UtilityMainInput from './UtilityMainInput.vue';
const formElement = ref(null);

const errorMessage = ref(null);
const form = ref({
  name: null,
  subject: null,
  email: null,
  message: null
});

const submitForm = () => {
  if (!form.value.name || !form.value.subject || !form.value.message) {
    console.log(form.value);
    errorMessage.value = "please make sure your 'fullname', 'subject', and 'message' fields are filled";
  } else if (!/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(form.value.email)) {
    errorMessage.value = "please fill in a valid 'email'";
  } else if (form.value.message.length < 3) {
    errorMessage.value = "please add some more context to the 'message'";
  } else {
    console.log("button clicked");
    console.log(form.value);
    formSubmit();
  }
};

const formSubmit = () => {
  const formElement = document.querySelector('form');
  console.log(formElement);
  // formElement.submit();
};

function test(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
</script>

<template>
  <form action="https://formsubmit.co/info@example.co.uk" method="POST" ref="formm">
    <UtilityMainInput name="Name" placeholder="Full Name" inputType="text" controlType="input" v-model="form.name" />
    <UtilityMainInput name="Subject" placeholder="Subject" inputType="text" controlType="input" v-model="form.subject" />
    <UtilityMainInput name="Email" placeholder="Email Address" inputType="email" controlType="input"
      v-model="form.email" />
    <UtilityMainInput name="Message" placeholder="Tell us anything" inputType="textarea" controlType="textarea"
      v-model="form.message" />
    <div class="empty-height"></div>
    <button @click="submitForm">Send Message</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

```js
<template>
    <div class="normal-form">
        <label :for="name" class="label">
            {{ name }}
        </label>
        <!-- text input -->
        <input v-if="controlType === 'input' && inputType === 'text'" type="text" maxlength="50" :name="name"
            :value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)">
        <!-- email input -->
        <input v-if="controlType === 'input' && inputType === 'email'" type="email" :name="name" :value="modelValue"
            @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)">
        <!-- textarea input -->
        <div class="textarea" v-if="controlType === 'textarea'">
            <textarea :name="name" :value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)">
            </textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    emits: ['update:modelValue'],
    props: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        placeholder: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: "text goes here"
        },
        inputType: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: "text"
        },
        controlType: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: 'input'
        },
        modelValue: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer with example. i really appreciate